# Add bookmarks and cross references to a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

In Word 2010 I want to add text to a document, bookmark this text and then cross reference this text in the header and footer of the document.

Can this be recorded or will I have to code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Yes you can record in Word - allthough with some limitations as you can't navigate thru your text by mouse when in recording mode; the generated code will be ugly and full of "hard coding" but will give you an impression which objects, methods and properties might be relevant..

If you want a solution that is a bit more sustainable than a one-off, proper coding surely  is the way to go. You should make friends with the following in order to solve your task:

- the [Selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821411.aspx) object and its methods, especially `GoTo`, `Move` and its variants
- the way to [extend a cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840899.aspx) to mark text
- inserting text using various Insert... methods (e.g. `Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Bookmark" ...`)
- adding bookmarks to the [Bookmarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821971.aspx) collection
- understanding how to [manipulate headers & footers](http://books.google.at/books?id=n-2NtSJNHBYC&pg=PA469&lpg=PA469&dq=manipulate%20header%20word%20vba&source=bl&ots=GHKomHHf_u&sig=cVogJ9t2N45FQH_BDrRj3sCVo-Y&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rUcCUYbYF8aR0QXF-4Ag&ved=0CFQQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Try some coding and come back with more sopecific questions if you get stuck.